# Pre-Hilalian Hilalian dialects comparaison

Tags: historical-linguistics, arabic, dialects, semitic-languages, african-languages

What are the main differences between Pre-Hilalian Tunisian dialects ( or any other Maghrebi dialects ) and the Hilalian ones ( Pronunciation , vocabulary ... ) . 
Let’s take the dialect I speak as an exemple : The /q/ is maintained , “Enti” (you) is used for both male and female , interdentals are maintained , no diphthongs ( “lil” for night , although my grandma , whose from Bizerte , says “leyl” with the diphthongs maintained) , there are many worlds of latin origin : kayyes ( trig/triq in other dialects , from the latin word callis ) , qattus ( cat ) , kurda ( rope ) , karrusa ( carriage from latin carrus ) , kalsita ( sock from latin calcia ) ...

Comment: The main difference is that Hilalian pronounce [g] and pre-Hilalian [q]. This distinctive feature is spread in the whole of North African Arabic varieties. As for other differences, as the subvarieties of Hilalian and pre-Hilalian are not homogeneous, you need to find what these subvarieties have in common before to know the differences between them.

Comment: @amegnunsen. The realisation of ق as /g/ is typical of Bedouin-type dialects in all parts of the Arab world, while its realisation as /q/ or as a glottal stop is typical of urban dialects. This is not specific to the Maghrib.